# If $X_n \overset{d}{\to}X$, and $a_n \to a$ where $a$ is a continuity point of $F_X$, is it true that $F_{X_n}(a_n) \to F_X(a)$?

Tags: probability

I was thinking about reducing the analysis to the interval around $a$ where $F_X$ is continuous but I can't see how to link this to $F_{X_n}$... Any idea would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to prove this statement is to use Slutsky's theorem: 
$a_n\to a$ implies $a_n \overset{p}{\to}a$, and together with $X_n \overset{d}{\to}X$ we get 
$$
X_n - a_n \overset{d}{\to}X - a.
$$
Finally note that if $a$ is a continuity point of $F_X$ then $0$ is a continuity point of $F_{X-a}$, and then
$$
F_{X_n-a_n}(0) \to F_{X-a}(0).
$$
L.h.s. is exactly $F_{X_n-a_n}(0) = F_{X_n}(a_n)$, r.h.s. is $F_{X-a}(0) = F_X(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is true. All you have to do exploit monotonicity of distribution functions. It is enough to consider the special cases $a_n$ increasing to $a$ and $a_n$ decreasing to $a$. In the first case $F_n(a_n) \leq F_n(a) \to F(a)$; also, if $\epsilon >0$ then $a_n > a- \epsilon >0$ for $n$ sufficiently large so $\lim \inf F_n(a_n) \geq \lim \inf F_n(a-\epsilon )=F(a-\epsilon ) \to F(a)$ as $\epsilon  \to 0$ through positive values such that $F$ is continuous at $a-\epsilon $. A similar argument works in the second case.

Comment: Wouldn't considering only monotonous functions be a lack of generality? What about considering just a convergent sequence and then working with a convergent subsequence of this sequence? I guess we would need the sequence $F_n(a_n)$ to converge then...

Comment: $F=F_X$ and $F_n=F_{X_{n}}$ are monotone functions so I am not making any extra assumption. In fact the statement is false if you replace distribution functions by general functions.